# PhpStorm: Add blank lines around if/else

Tags: php, phpstorm

I would like to configure PhpStorm this way:

`If/Else`Blocks in PHP code should be separated with a blank line.

Example:

```
<?php
$hello = true;
if($hello) {
echo "Hello";
} else {
echo "Bye";
}
echo "...my friend";
?>
```

should become

```
<?php
$hello = true;

if($hello) {
echo "Hello";
} else {
echo "Bye";
}

echo "...my friend";
?>
```

I did not find any information about that in the JetBrains documentation.

Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: There is no such setting in PhpStorm's Code Style settings. Feel free to submit Feature Request ticket at Issue Tracker -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI . But please check for any existing tickets before making your own.

Comment: I would try the PhpStorm Code Style settings for blank lines: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/code-style-php.html#d468738e975

Comment: I can not find any settings for blank lines before and after `if/else`. Could you tell me which point in the code style settings is the point I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: go to File>Settings>Editor>Live Templates; there will be a list of languages - select 'PHP', then click plus on the right; there you can create a template like

```
if(){
echo '';
} else {
echo '';
}
```

(line breaks will be preserved), then write an abbreviation for the template and define context to 'PHP'.
Then you can write the abbreviation of this template and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to insert it in any PHP file.