# PhpStorm: Remove unnecessary whitespaces

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm to refactor an old web project. The code style is a little bit uncommon and I do not like it very much.

**For example:**

```
case 'test'            :
```

instead of

```
case 'test':
```

Any idea how to remove these unnecessary whitespaces with PhpStorm? I tried to get rid of them using the Code Style settings, but I did not find a solution yet.

Comment: Same suggestion as for your another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412746/phpstorm-add-blank-lines-around-if-else

Comment: How about using regex with find-replace?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at to PhpStorm short-keys in its documentation.
Try: `ctrl` + `alt` + `L`